# How to change my background color of svg place in html object element

Tags: jquery, css, html, django-templates

How can i change the background color of svg place in html object element .Using CSS ,Jquery  or Javascript
my svg image is collected from an extended source in django static file

html

```
<object  id="object" type="image/svg+xml" data="{% static 'images/icons/Businessopportunities.svg' %}"></object>
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1):

You have to open your web console and inspect the `svg` image. Find the element that you want to change the color of and then open the `svg` image in your preferred code editor, find the element again and assign a custom class to it.

Style that class ass normal in your `css` file.

As you don't provide the image you want to colorize, I cannot help you further on this. If you don't manage to make this, please provide the code of your image and tell us, what should be colorized.

Comment: Look at my html code .You will see that the image is being collected from a source .Using django static file

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but that does not help, we have no code of the actual image. As you maybe know, `svg` images are made up of `html` code, so you can open them in your text editor and assign classes to some elements inside it. It's that code that you have to inspect, to find the element you want to colorize by `css` or `js`. If you add a class or an id to it, you can simply refer to it.

Comment: Actually, svg is based on XML and therefore not really html, but has the same syntax / structure and can be embedded in html.

Comment: @frontend_dev That's absolutely correct. I apologize for the inaccurate or even slightly wrong choice of words.

Comment: No prob, did not want to nitpick, but thought this should be clarified ;)

Comment: Yes, absolutely!